# Python _ Project Euler Question 2 - Why my answer code is wrong?

Tags: python-3.9

Q: By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My Code:

```
x = 1
y = 2
ans = 0
evens = []
while x <= 4000000:
    ans = x + y
    x = y
    y = ans
    if ans % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(ans)
print(sum(evens))
```

My result is 461373**0** while it should be 461373**2**.
What am I don't understand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print(evens)` inside loop to see what you missed. Now, first 2 is not printed.

First even, 2, is not inserted to the `evens`, so one of ways to correct the code is  inserting 2 into evens right before starting a loop. There might be many ways to solve this issue.

```py
x = 1
y = 2
ans = 0
evens = [2]
while x <= 4000000:
    ans = x + y
    x = y
    y = ans
    if ans % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(ans)
    print(evens) # to debug what are in in a 'evens' list
print(sum(evens)) 
# 4613730
```

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping over 2.

`ans` is first checked with the value of 3.

`ans = x + y` is `3` since you start with `x = 1` and `y = 2`

Comment: @JamesRobers 

But it says in the question that the first figure in Fibonacci sequence is 1 and not 0: Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms. –

Comment: Where you start is not the issue, you were skipping over an even valued term (2). You have to "find the sum of the even-valued terms". You were not adding 2 to your `evens` list because your `ans` was set to 3 before you checked if it was even, you missed the check for 1 and 2. @Sangkeun Park gave you the answer.